# Automatically changing git submodule URL when pushing

Tags: git, git-submodules

There is a private host A that is the master source repository for a project that also uses submodules from the same host A.

I'd like to set up (semi-)automatic publishing of the sources from a branch on host A to a public host B (say, github), so that the submodule references would contain URL-s with host B instead of host A, so that public checkouts would work without manual intervention. Doing that with minimal surgery, as the submodule repositories all contain the same commits from a single master branch.

Are there any best practices or utilities for doing such surgery, without "re-writing history" if possible ?

Comment: Probably you want to use relative submodule path.

Comment: This does not change the fact that the commit that adds the cubmodule contains (git show) the URL. Thus most probably includes the content in the commit hash...

Comment: What do you mean? You can have relative path in `.gitmodules` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-reading git-submodules docs and http://blog.tremily.us/posts/Relative_submodules/ the problem "solved itself".